# How do I add vertical space of 10pt between the rows so that it is not as congested, while still maintaining the row colors?

Tags: tables, rowcolor

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    String Tension & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
    kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    15 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 &
    6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    20 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    25 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    30 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    35 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add a vertical space of 10pt between each row and 5 pt between the row of rebound height and the trials. When I do \vspace{10pt} the extra space is white and I do not know how to color the extra space generated with vspace. Additionally, vspace does not work between the rebound height and trials. Thanks!
[[image: Output with current code1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to set `\extrarowheight` to 10pt (`array` package required).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \renewcommand\extrarowheight{10pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    String Tension & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
    kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    15 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 &
    6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    20 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    25 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    30 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    35 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the row data more centered vertically, one could add a 5pt (above and below) stack-gap to a single entry on each row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,stackengine}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    String Tension & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
    kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    \addstackgap[5pt]{15} & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 &
    6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    \addstackgap[5pt]{20} & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    \addstackgap[5pt]{25} & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    \addstackgap[5pt]{30} & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    \addstackgap[5pt]{35} & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one could renew the value of `\arraystretch`.  However, this approach does not set specific point value increases, but is rather a space increase proportional in some way to the default baselineskip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    String Tension & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
    kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    15 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 &
    6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    20 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    25 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
    30 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
    35 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One solution using the new `tabularray`package, see [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\definecolor{oddrows}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.902}
\definecolor{evenrows}{rgb}{0.949,0.949,0.949}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec=ccccccccc,
            row{odd}=oddrows,
            row{even}=evenrows,
            row{1,2}=white,
        }
        \toprule
        String Tension & \SetCell[c=8]{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
        kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
        \midrule
        15 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        20 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        25 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        30 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        35 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularray solution]

This has increased vertical spacing by default. If you want to increase the spacing further, you can specify the `rowsep` parameter (default `2pt`). You can also specify a different `rowsep` for the first two rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\definecolor{oddrows}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.902}
\definecolor{evenrows}{rgb}{0.949,0.949,0.949}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec=ccccccccc,
            row{odd}=oddrows,
            row{even}=evenrows,
            rowsep=5pt,
            row{1,2}={white,rowsep=2.5pt}
        }
        \toprule
        String Tension & \SetCell[c=8]{c}{Rebound Height / m $\pm$ 0.05 m}\\
        kg/ $\pm$ 0.5 & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8\\
        \midrule
        15 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        20 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        25 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        30 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        35 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 3.345 & 4.345 & 5.345 & 6.345 & 7.345 & 8.345\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Raw Data}
    \label{tab:Raw Data}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularray with increased vertical spacing]

There are also other parameters, eg. `abovesep` and `belowsep` to control the spacing above and below each row separately. See `Table 3.1` in the [tabularray documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for a complete list.